# Custom Gutenburg Block Error on inputfield text input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, ecmascript-5, wordpress-gutenberg

In the editor where the block is generated I create a wp.element, below is the code used.

```
edit: function( props ) {       

    function AddPolygons() 
    {
        var coOrdInputvalue = props.attributes.polygonArrayViewAdd.length;
        var i = (coOrdInputvalue/5);

        coOrdlabel = wp.element.createElement("p", null, "Map point Co-Ords" );
        coOrdtextbox = wp.element.createElement("input", { type: "text", value: "", onChange: onChangeMapPoint });
        coOrdbutton = wp.element.createElement("button", {className: "buttonPolygonData", id:"mapPoint"+i, onClick: setActivePolygon}, "Set");
        Quotelabel = wp.element.createElement("p", null, "Set Quotation");
        Quotetextbox = wp.element.createElement("input", { type: "text", value: "", id:"Quote"+i, onChange: onChangeQuote });

        var arrayAdded = [coOrdlabel, coOrdtextbox, coOrdbutton, Quotelabel, Quotetextbox];
        polygonArrayViewAdd = polygonArrayViewAdd.concat(arrayAdded);

        props.setAttributes({ polygonArrayViewAdd: polygonArrayViewAdd });
        console.log("Add to view"); 
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     
    return wp.element.createElement( 

        wp.element.Fragment, 
        null,   
        wp.element.createElement(
                    InspectorControls,
                    null,
                    wp.element.createElement(PanelBody, {
                        title:'Poloygon List',
                        initialOpen: true
                    },

                    button = wp.element.createElement("button", {onClick: AddPolygons}, "Add Polygons"),

                    wp.element.createElement( 

                        wp.editor.RichText, {
                            tagName: 'div',
                            id: 'polydiv',
                            key: 'editable',
                            value: props.attributes.polygonArrayViewAdd
                        } 
                    ),
                    button = wp.element.createElement("button", {onClick: ClearPolygons}, "Clear Polygons"),
                    )
                ),

        wp.element.createElement('img', {src: props.attributes.mediaURL,style: {display:"none"}}),


    );
},
```

The views are displayed in the RichText element, can I put the input boxes inside a RichText as im getting this error
react-dom.min.js?ver=16.13.1:32 Uncaught TypeError: s is not a function,

below is the block with the input fields been generated from clicking the add polygon button, the input boxes appear but don't allow text to be inputted and therefore saved.

[image: view of inspectorcontrols and eror]

Comment: The function `ClearPolygons` is missing with your edit() function - is it defined somewhere else? If the function is missing, it will throw an error like in your screenshot.

Comment: Just got the solution today, was the RichText element needed more to it, their was significant code added to correct this solution that I cannot answer here.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the issue. After looking at your solution, perhaps using TextControl might simplify your code (https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/text-control/)

Answer (score 0):

All that needed to be changed was the RichText element to have more parameters to it

```
                    wp.element.createElement( wp.blockEditor.RichText, Object.assign( props, {
                        value: props.attributes.polygonArrayViewAdd, 
                        onChange: function(content) {
                            var boxesCoOrdTextBox = document.getElementsByClassName("CoOrdTextBox");

                        },
                        onClick: function (event) {
                            console.log(event.target.id);
                            }
                            if(event.target.id.includes("mapPoint"))
                            {   
                                props.setAttributes({ CurrentMap: event.target.id });
                                return;
                            }
                        },
                    } ) ),
```

Comment: You are welcome to accept your own answer - https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer